# Programmatically create Excel workbooks which will display a user form on opening

Tags: vba, excel

In the automation tool trainer has to mention student names and using that name the Excel file will be created. Example: `Shreesha_xlsx.xlsx`

After assigning the test with their names, IF the students open the Excel file of their own, THEN they should be able to see the userform (Welcome screen) and next screen is answering the questions.

The following code is that to assign the Excel file under the student name and after that I have also pasted the code that when user clicks on the Excel file it should open with userform.

Altogether it is calling userform of one Excel file in another without setting any reference.

```
Sub Button2_Click()
Dim s(6 To 100) As String
Dim stname As String
Dim status As String
Dim mypath As String
Dim u As String

u = "_xlsx"

 For i = 6 To 100

 s(i) = Range("E" & i).Value
  stname = s(i) & "" & u

If s(i) = "" Then
      ActiveWorkbook.Open = False
End If
  'in case of Run time error    
  On Error GoTo jamun:

mypath = Range("B1").Value & "\" & stname
Workbooks.Add.SaveAs filename:=mypath
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Range("B" & i).Value = mypath & "_assigning..."
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")
Range("F" & i).Value = "Done"
Range("B" & i).Value = mypath & "_assigned"
Range("B" & i).Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="mypath", TextToDisplay:=Range("B" & i).Value
Range("B" & i).Select
Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Address = Range("B1").Value
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Next
MsgBox "Test assigned successfully"

Exit Sub
jamun:
      MsgBox "Test assigned successfully"
End Sub
```

Now the following code is that when they open, they should see the userform

```
    enter code here

Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim objFolder As Folder
Dim objFile As File
Dim strpath As String
Dim a As Workbook
Dim filename As String
strpath = Range("B1").Value
Set objFolder = FSO.GetFolder(strpath)
If objFolder.Files.Count = 0 Then
MsgBox "No files were found....", vbExclamation
End If
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
a = "Good" 'userform name is good
    Workbook.Open (a)
    VBA.UserForms.Add(a).Show
    a.Show
Next objFile
End Sub
```

and don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: I suggest that you generate the assignment files from a template, which contains the userform used for submitting the assignment. Not sure I understood your problem completely though. Plz try to better explain it.

Comment: My problem is that I want to write a code in seperate excel file so that  when the user clicks on the excel file for taking up the test he should first see the userform  that says him "all the best" .  That is calling userform from a different excel file.

Comment: Hi again. As I told you, your problem needs more explnation. What I mostly do not understand is why you want the form to be invoked from a code that resides in the master workbook, and why you are reluctant to the idea of using a template which contains that form, which is in my view the logical approach. It is very difficult to achieve invoking a form that resides in another workbook, this is by design, mainly because of security issues.

Comment: Ultimately, you can write some code to "import" a form from another WB, but you will invoke the copy in the context of the current workbook. This is not a good idea, it is better to have the form in a template...

Comment: How do I get the form in a template

Comment: The purpose of calling the form is to wish the student create a link with the command button to take up the test. It is just like a home screen.Altogether the idea is to generate question paper via vba in excel and main part is to hide the excel and show only the forms

Comment: Am getting my hope back and pls do let me know about the template

Answer (score 1):

1) Create an excel workbook with the desired form

2) Write code to open the form on Workbook_Open()

3) Write code in the form to fill the workbook with questions and whatever other information when the WB opens. All in all, make the behavior of the file exactly as you want it to behave when it opens to the student.

4) Save your file as a template (extension .xltm), let's say examTemplate.xltm

5) Now when you will generate exam files from the master file, generate them from the template. Consider changing this part of your code:

> Workbooks.Add.SaveAs filename:=mypath
>
> ActiveWorkbook.Close

Instead of this, we generate the file from the template:

```
Dim neWB as Workbook
Set newWB = Workbooks.Add("examTemplate.xltm") ' <~~~ generate from template
```

The freshly generated newWB inherits the template. That is, it has all its data, code, controls and forms. At this point, you can fill some data in newWB, things related to the assignment. That is, questions, or some parameters that will indicate where to fetch the questions, so that the form can access these parameters and do the work. Ideally, these parameters can be embedded in a hidden sheet. After then:

```
newWB.SaveAs filename:=mypath ' <~~ save it as macro-enabled .xlsm
newWB.Close
```

From that point, I think you can continue with with the same logic. The radical change in the approach is that the form will be readily embedded in the new workbook, not invoked from another workbook.

**EDIT:** you want your workbook to only show only the Form but never the workbook itself. This can be achieved by adding the following event handler to the *ThisWorkbook* code module of your template file:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If InStr(1, Me.Name, ".xltm") > 1 Then Exit Sub ' <~~ to apply only to chidren no to template itself
    With Me.Application
       .Visible = False
       .DisplayAlerts = False
       MyForm.Show
       .Visible = True
    End With
    Me.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: I am really proud of you and its working fine. I need few more hints. 1.

Comment: 1. When the workbook getting created it is showing the error " Privacy Warning The document contains macros, ActiveX controls, XML expansion pack information, or web components. These may include personal Information that cannot be removed by document Inspector "

Comment: 2. Write code in the form to fill the workbook with questions and whatever other information when the WB opens. All in all, make the behavior of the file exactly as you want it to behave when it opens to the student.

Comment: The freshly generated newWB inherits the template. That is, it has all its data, code, controls and forms. At this point, you can fill some data in newWB, things related to the assignment. That is, questions, or some parameters that will indicate where to fetch the questions, so that the form can access these parameters and do the work.

Comment: For 1, try removing the warning message by using Application.displayalerts = false. For 2, these are guidelines to write code that achieves what you want in your specific application.

Comment: Hello Sir, when I add template, I dont want to see the menu bar and ribbon etc. It has to look exaclty like the userform wherein it has no menus etc.

Comment: Using template I can see menu and ribbon and how to remove them

Comment: The template that i create should not be having row numbers, column names, exaclty it looks like user form. is there any alternative apart from the template.....?

Comment: `Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Application.Visible = False
   UserForm1.Show
 End Sub`

Comment: Am sorry, sir am not getting the expected output. Please tel me if any alter nate solution is there. The above code that you mentioned where I will add so that all the students when they open there excel sheet they can see the user form

Comment: Thank You sir for the reply, Sir the previous code Dim neWB as Workbook
Set newWB = Workbooks.Add("examTemplate.xltm") ' is working fine. But the concern what i have is that , If the user/ student opens the excel file they can able to see the template but along with this they can also able to see the quick access tool bar, menu bar etc.

Comment: If I get an opportunity to attach my file , definitely i convey the exact problem . After executing the edit code am unable to assign test only sir.... Please do me the favour

Comment: Sir i created a template and that includes the sheet1 with command button and also i created the user form in the same template. i have written the code for command button  to open the user form and  when i execute the code it's not working. (Dim neWB as Workbook
Set newWB = Workbooks.Add("examTemplate.xltm")

Comment: You probably need to give it the full path of the template file

Comment: Sir it's working fine. now the code i have changed as Set neWb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\nanoo.xls"). That is instead of template i created normal excel and included user form in that and the above code i added and its now time to get questions from excel to user form. Thank you sir

Comment: In the nanoo. xls i have a command button on the sheet1 and created user form  and linked command button and the user form

Comment: I will come back to ask more help from you sir , your hints are driving me towards my goal. Thank you alot sir

Comment: Sir, I want to pull the questions from sheet 2 named as Questions (Sheet 2 name)  to User form and in the user form i have a field for Questions, and multiple choice answers and a combo box to check for the options from drop down list and select the answer and click next button and it should pull the next question.

Comment: You can initiatlize the form and populate the lists and questions in the subroutine `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` in the form's code module.

Comment: @shree let me understand your problem. Is it that you want to open the form  and hide the workbook as soon as it opens? is that it? What did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: Sir now everything is working fine. Actually the failing part was that, if i use template it was not supporting macro.So i created a template kind of and saved it as nanoo.xlsx

Comment: Now i would like to have the questions in nanoo(excel) that has user form and the questions that are from the original workbook should be pulled to this(nanoo) user form and please guide me

Comment: in Form_Initialize, you can open the master workbook, acces the worksheet where the questions are, copy them from there. Dim wb as workbook; set wb=Application.workbooks.open(master); etc.

Comment: Sir actually I did not get this point. Can you please clarify me

Comment: Sir if you don't mind can you please guide me with the code and the Master workbook(Where i have questions in sheet2) name is Mac and the sheet2 name is Questions. and the user form excel name is nanoo.

Comment: With depression am waiting for the reply, for the code. Please let me know the code. I am trying by all means but no hopes

Comment: @shrees, it is about time to close this topic. I tried my best to help you to design an approach to achieve your target, but I can not write the code for you. The best that we could do for now is to close this topic, then you can open another question where you can show what you did so far, where it is blocking, and I, as well as others, will be more than happy to help you further :)